# Are operations upon index-classes (rather than index-sets) allowed in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

Why we always see extended operations, like arbitrary unions, products, etc. in different parts of mathematics in the form of extensions of finite ones upon arbitrary *sets* (called index set)? Why never use an index-*class* for a proper class?

EDIT:
Of course I think this a reason, for example, that in the context of category theory, some theorems only hold for small/locally small categories: we are not allowed to operate upon arbitrary proper classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restrictions on what you can use proper classes for are there to make sure that everything you write down can actually be proved to exist using the restricted set-building axioms of ZF set theory. We can prove once and for all that a union or product (or whatever) indexed by a *set* will always describe something that has an existence proof, but this proof generally doesn't go through if the indices are pulled from a proper class.

It's more of a rule of thumb than an absolute truth, though -- for example, an *intersection* indexed by a proper class is actually unproblematic from a ZF point of view. But it is much easier to *remember* simply not using proper classes for indexing, and the cases where you need the exceptions are sufficiently rare that it is cost-effective (in mental effort) simply to say not to index by proper classes, and in the few cases where that is insufficient argue directly from the axioms instead of relying on the slick index notation.

The reason why ZF restricts set-building in the first place is to avoid allowing the reasoning that leads to set-theoretical paradoxes such as *Russel's* or *Buralli-Forti's* paradox. There are a few competing suggestions for other restrictions that aim to achieve that by other means, but the general consensus is that the ZF restrictions are the most convenient to stay within for most ordinary mathematics.

Comment: Perfect answer! Just, don't you think that we can not therefore handle many notions and facts that are not made in a set-based manner? For example, it's not possible (or at least common, due to my knowledge) to talk about limits of categories on "large" diagrams. It seems that not many people are interested to check/talk about such exceptions!

Comment: @Amir.HKiani: Category theory is one of the few areas where the restrictions of ZF set theory genuinely create extra work -- hence the distinction between small and large categories and so forth. There's been some suggestions of using a different foundation for category theory for this reason, such as Quine's NF -- but those are weird in their own ways and would just make it difficult to draw useful connections between category theory and the _rest_ of mathematics (where everyone is quite happy with ZF).

Comment: So it looks like most category theorists are minded to grin and bear it, and perhaps come up with something like Grothendieck universes as a way to systematize the usual workarounds they need.

Answer (score 1):

The greatest operation that you will see is the power of the universe $V^A$ with $A$ set. This is a proper class, but the *elements* are sets: functions $f:A\longrightarrow V$. In the case $\text{set}^{\text{proper class}}$ the possible "elements" are proper classes.